# Duplicar página de categorias

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo una página donde se me muestran las categorias **loop-archive.php** y tengo otra página **loop-archive2.php** donde quiero que también aparezcan las categorías, ¿cómo hago para que me muestren ahi tambien las categorias?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me da ese error cuando duplico el contenido del loop-archive.php en el nuevo loop-archive2.php

Adjunto el código que estoy usando

```html
<div  id="new">

<?php if ( ! have_posts() ) : ?>
  <h1><?php _e( 'Not Found', 'limon' ); ?></h1>
  <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but the page you requested could not be found. Perhaps searching will help.', 'limon' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
    


                <div id="slide_home" class="full marginBottom_2em marginTop_1em">
                    <?php include('slide_nuevo.php')?>
                </div>

    
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="marginBottom_1em marginTop_1em">
            
         <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
             <header>
     <?php $url=get_permalink();?>
             </header>
           

   
                 
     <div class="marginTop_1em">
                     
                        <?php 
      $id = $post->ID;
      $categorias = get_the_terms($id, 'tipos-de-tarifas');
      $count = 0; 
      foreach($categorias as $categoria){
      $count ++;
      if($count == 1){
      $name = $categoria->slug;
      $id = $categoria->term_id;
      $name_id = 'tipos-de-tarifas_'.$id;
      $prueba = get_field('color', $name_id);
       }
      }
      ;?>
                        

         
                        
                        
                        
                       
                        <div class="grid_3 white paddingBottom_1em">
                         <a style="width:280px;min-height:200px!important;max-height:200px!important;" class="link" href="<?php echo $url;?>" ><br /></a>
                         <h3 class="white padding_1em"><?php the_field('velocidad'); ?></h3>
                         <div class="precio whitecolor padding_1em" style="background:<?php echo $prueba;?>;">
                          <p class="digitos"><?php the_field('precio'); ?></p>
                    <p class="decimales">,<?php the_field('decimales_precio'); ?></p>
                    <p class="euros">€/mes</p>
                    <p class="condiciones"><?php the_field('condiciones'); ?></p>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
       </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="grid_9">
                         <h2 class="title left paddingTop_05em">
        <a title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'limon' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
       </h2>
                            <div class="right">
                            <?php 
      $id = $post->ID;
      $categorias = get_the_terms($id, 'tipos-de-tarifas');
      $count =  0;
      foreach($categorias as $categoria){
       $count++;
       //var_dump($categoria);
      $id = $categoria->term_id;
      $parent = $categoria->parent;
      if($count > 1){
       break;
      }
      //$ids = array_fill(0, 6, $id);
      //var_dump($ids);
       if($id == 15){
        }elseif($parent == 15){ }else{echo __('<a class="coberturas_button" href="#">Ver cobertura</a>', 'limon');}
      }
      ?>
                            
                            <a id="contratar_button" class="inline cboxElement" href="#formulario"><?php echo __('Alta online', 'limon');?></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <ul class="caracteristicas">
                            
                            <?php $caracteristicas = get_field('caracteristicas');
         $velocidad = get_field('velocidad_de_bajada_y_subida');
        
         $count = 0;
         if (!empty($caracteristicas)){
          foreach( $caracteristicas as $caracteristica){
           $count ++;
           $caracteristica = $caracteristica['caracteristica'];
           $par = $count%2;
           if($par != 0){
             echo '<li class="grid_5 alpha omega izq"><p class="padding_1em">'.$caracteristica.'. </p></li>';
           }else{
            echo '<li class="grid_4 right alpha omega der"><p class="padding_1em">'.$caracteristica.'. </p></li>';
           }
             
          } 
          
          
            
          
           
          
          
          
       }?>
                             <div class="clear"></div>
                            </ul>
                            <?php if($velocidad){ 
        echo '<ul class="caracteristicas"><li class=""><p class="padding_1em"><strong>Velocidad de bajada/subida: '.$velocidad.'</strong></p></li></ul>';
        }?>
                            
                        </div><!--grid_9-->
                        
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        
     </div><!--marginTop_1em-->
     
      
   
             <footer>
             </footer>
         </article>
   <div class="clear"></div>
  </div><!--marginBottom_1em-->
<?php endwhile; // End the loop. Whew. ?>
  <div class="clear"></div>  
  <!-- <nav class="grid_8 textAlignRight"> Ocultar paginacion
         <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
  </nav> -->
 

<div class="clear"></div>  
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
</div>
```

Comment: Se me ocurre que podría ser usando un if.. si estás en esta categoria que muestre el include... pero no se como hacerlo ayuda pls

Comment: Me da la impresión de que ese archivo fuese parte de un theme, y no está pensado para cargarse de forma individual. ¿Seguro que el original lo cargas como `http://www.dominio.com/loop-archive.php` ?

Comment: Sí, es de un theme,... no sé de donde lo carga, lo que quiero es que un un contenido X solo se me cargue en una página de categorías pero no sé como hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

el **foreach** debes ponerlo dentro del siguiente if:

```
if ( $categorias && !is_wp_error( $categorias) ) {

    foreach foreach($categorias as $categoria){
    ...
    }

}
```